# jQuery (with Django): Appending URL to List with click event

Tags: jquery, html, url, click, append

When I add something to the 'patient_medications' list from the medicines list, I want to be able to delete it with the class click event for 'medication-on'.  The click event works for medications that are generated from the original code, but my additions do not delete when clicked.  What am I doing wrong?  Is something wrong with this line?

```
$('#patient_medications').append('<li><a href="#" class="medication-on" data-cost='+cost+'>'+med_name+'</a></li>');
```

The link is added but clicking does not cause the event.

I would also appreciate any guidance on the best way to do something like this with a very large amount of medications, say, generate the urls for all medicines from a search box or have a cool widget to select some based on user input.

Thank you.

```
<ul id='patient_medications'>
{% for med in patient.medications.all %}
       <li><a href="#" class="medication-on" data-cost="{{med.m_cost}}">{{med.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Total Cost (30-day supply):</h4>
<div id="costs">
{{sum.m_cost__sum}}
</div>
<h3>Available Medications:</h3>
{% for m in medications %}
    <li><a href="#" class="medication-link" data-cost="{{m.m_cost}}">{{m.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.medication-on').click(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var cost = link.data("cost");
    var costs = $('#costs');
    var cur_cost = parseFloat(costs.html());
    var result = cur_cost - cost;
    costs.html(result);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
$('.medication-link').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    var med_name = link.html();
    var cost = link.data("cost");
    $('#patient_medications').append('<li><a href="#" class="medication-on" data-cost='+cost+'>'+med_name+'</a></li>');
    var costs = $('#costs');
    var cur_cost = parseFloat(costs.html());
    var result = cur_cost + cost;
    costs.html(result);
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should use **.on()** function instead of **.click()**, since the elements are appended dynamically in the html document. Older jQuery versions use **.live()** instead.
**[Link - .on() api reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: That does not seem to work either, unless I am misunderstanding?  The old links work but the new ones do not.